# Links disable when I click on a 1 link

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I have a page set up with 3 posts, and within eacht post there is gallery that is hidden. When I click on a visit button within the post, the gallery slides open and the page scrolls to the gallery. When the gallery is open, I can click on the end visit button, the gallery closes and the page scrolls to the top of the post

When I click on a visit button that is on, say, the second post, the visit button of the first post is disabled. When I click on the visit button of the 3rd post, the button of post one and two are disabled.
If I click on the 1st post, the 2nd and 3rd visit buttons are active, but they will not scroll to the gallery like they are supposed to.
And when the 2nd gallery is open, it scrolls up all the way to the first post when I click on the end visit button.

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/Jarmal/fckct).

Comment: As Ariel said you have nothing with class `post`, also you have a mismatch closing `</div>`. You really should create a fiddle.

Comment: Hey Pedram, Stackoverflow doesn't seem to show the 'div class=post' part, but it's there ;).
Here's my fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/Jarmal/fckct

Comment: Please post **relevant** parts of the code here.

Comment: I don't know what causes the problem, that's why I posted all the code

Answer (score 0):

It says: `.closest('.post')` but I don't see anything with the post class.

I suggest you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with the full source code, including all 3 posts, and I will update my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks :d. When I enter my code is jsfiddle it gives me this error message whn I click on a button :{"error": "Please use POST request"}

But this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Jarmal/fckct/

Thanks in adcance :D

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is going on. The error you are getting (about post) is because `$.scrollTo()` does not exist. If I remove it, everything seems OK to me (keeping in mind I don't really know what you are trying to do), except it doesn't scroll, which makes sense since I removed the scroll commands. If not scrolling is the problem you are having then you need to include a plugin to accomplish whatever scrollTo means to you (or write it yourself).

Comment: I've included the plugin I'm using in my fiddle. The plugin on it's own is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jarmal/YyeN3/).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on jsFiddle, so I've included a [link](http://www.jarmalsharif.nl/prototype.zip) to download it.

Comment: @JarmalMartis In the stylesheet add `clear: both;` to the style for `.post .gallery`. The reason it wasn't working before is that without the clear the position of the gallery is mixed with the floated elements above, and it was impossible to scroll to it.